# c# error al recorrer objetos de forma dinamica

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, reflection

Buenos dias a todos.

Tengo un proyecto webapi montado con el patron repository y necesito hacer una modificación a la respuesta que me ofrece el metodo `_repository.getByFilter(...)`. Esto devuelve un `IQueryable` y necesito recorrer todos los objetos de esta lista comprobando si alguna de las propiedades tiene un atributo personalizado (`EncryptedData`). Si es así, encripto el valor.

El problema es que estos objetos pueden tener propiedadess que sean `ICollection` u otros objetos de clases propias.

Para intentar solventar esto, he montado estas tres funciones:

```
private IQueryable<T> EncryptDecrypt(IQueryable<T> queryable, bool encrypt)
{
    var encriptedProperty = typeof(T).GetProperties().Where(
        p => p.CustomAttributes.Any(at => at.AttributeType == typeof(Konecta.Core.Attributes.EncryptedData))
    );
    var collectionProperty = typeof(T).GetProperties().Where(p => p.PropertyType.Name.Contains("ICollection"));

    if (encriptedProperty.Count() != 0 || collectionProperty.Count() != 0)
    {
        foreach (T obj in queryable)
        {
            if (encriptedProperty.Count() > 0)
            {
                foreach (var ep in encriptedProperty)
                {
                    ep.SetValue(obj, Convert.ChangeType(DecryptDB(ep.GetValue(obj, null).ToString()), ep.PropertyType), null);
                }
            }
            if (collectionProperty.Count() > 0)
            {
                foreach (var cp in collectionProperty)
                {
                    EncryptDecrypt((ICollection<cp.PropertyType>)cp.GetValue(obj, null), true);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return queryable;
}

private ICollection<T> EncryptDecrypt(ICollection<T> collection, bool encrypt)
{
    var encriptedProperty = typeof(T).GetProperties().Where(
        p => p.CustomAttributes.Any(at => at.AttributeType == typeof(Konecta.Core.Attributes.EncryptedData))
    );
    var collectionProperty = typeof(T).GetProperties().Where(p => p.PropertyType.Name.Contains("ICollection"));

    if (encriptedProperty.Count() == 0 && collectionProperty.Count() == 0)
    {
        foreach (T obj in collection)
        {
            if (encriptedProperty.Count() > 0)
            {
                foreach (var ep in encriptedProperty)
                {
                    ep.SetValue(obj, Convert.ChangeType(DecryptDB(ep.GetValue(obj, null).ToString()), ep.PropertyType), null);
                }
            }
            if (collectionProperty.Count() > 0)
            {
                foreach (var cp in collectionProperty)
                {
                    EncryptDecrypt((ICollection<cp.PropertyType>)cp.GetValue(obj, null), true);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return collection;
}

private T EncryptDecrypt(T entity, bool encrypt)
{
    return entity;
}
```

En mi capa de logica de negocios tengo la siguiente linea:

```
EncryptDecrypt(_repository.SelectByFilter(where), true);
```

Así consigo que, el resultado del `SelectByFilter` entre por la primera de mis funciones (aun están a media), compruebo si alguna propiedad tiene mi atributo personalizado y, si es así, la encripto.

Despues compruebo si alguna propiedad es una collección, y envío el valor a la segunda función.

El problema es que la linea

```
EncryptDecrypt((ICollection<cp.PropertyType>)cp.GetValue(obj, null), true);
```

de la primera funcion me da un error:

> no se puede convertir `ICollection<cp.PropertyType>` a `IQueryable<T>`.

¿Alguien me puede decir que estoy haciendo mal?

También me gustaría saber si alguien me puede decir alguna forma mas eficiente de hacer todo esto para no necesitar tantas funciones.

Un saludo y gracias.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El error de conversion se debe a que `IQueryable` todavia no ha ejecutado la consulta mientras que `ICollection` trabaja con objetos que ya tienes, osea que ya estan en memoria. Ejecuta el metodo `ToList()` sobre el objeto `IQueryable` para poder hacer el casting exitosamente.

Y en cuanto la recomendacion es que no utilizes los atributos como forma de encriptacion porque reflection es muy lento. Intenta crear una interfaz que se encargara de marcar un objeto que puede ser encriptado:

```
public interface IObjetoEncriptable
{
   void Encriptar(Encriptador encriptador);
   void Desencriptar(Encriptador encriptador);
}
```

Luego implementas en cada objeto que soporta encriptacion la interfaz y defines la logica de encriptacion/desencriptador:

```
public class Paciente : IObjetoEncriptable
{ 
  public string Nombre {get;  set;}
  public string Direccion {get;set;}

  public void Encriptar(Encriptador e)
  {
    this.Nombre = e.Encriptar(this.Nombre);
    this.Direccion = e.Encriptar(this.Direccion);
  }

  publi void Desencriptador(Encriptador e)
  {
    this.Nombre = e.Desencriptar(this.Nombre);
    this.Direccion = e.Desencriptar(this.Direccion); 
  }
}

public class RecordMedico : IObjetoEncriptable
{
   public string TipoSange { get; set;}
   public string Telefono { get; set;}
   public Paciente Paciente { get; set;}

   public void Encriptar(Encriptador e)
   {
      this.TipoSangre = e.Encriptar(this.TipoSangre); 
     this.Telefono = e.Encriptar(this.Telefono); 
   }

   public void Encriptar(Encriptador e)
   {
      this.TipoSangre = e.Desencriptar(this.TipoSangre); 
      this.Telefono = e.Desencriptar(this.Telefono); 

      // encriptamos los objetos que requieren encriptacion/desencriptacion
      this.Paciente.Encriptar(e);
   }
}
```

Entonces ahora cuando en el repositorio para desencripta y encriptar solo debes de enviarle la instancia del encriptador por cada instancia encriptable:

```
public IEnumerable<RecordMedico> ObtenerRecordMedicoPacientes()
{
    var record = obtenerRecords();
    Encriptador encriptador = new Encriptador();
    foreach(RecordMedico record : record)
    {
      record.Desencriptar(encriptador);
      yield return record;
    }

}

public void GuardarRecordMedico(RecordMedico record)
{
   Encriptador encriptador = new Encriptador();
   record.Encriptar(encriptador);
   //...
}
```

Asi no tienes que buscar cual propiedad es encriptable.

Comment: Muchas gracias Einer por responder tan rapido. Te comento algo segun tu ejemplo.

Imagina que tu clase RecordMedico tiene dentro una propiedad de tipo Medico y a su vez, Medico tiene otra de tipo InformacionExtra. Puede darse el caso que la propiedad que quiero encriptar o desencriptar este en la clase InformacionExtra, por lo que tu ejemplo no me valdría, por eso uso Reflection, para crear funciones en las que, independientemente del tipo de la salida del getByFilter, recorra el objeto buscando que hay que encriptar o desencriptar.

Comment: Claro que es posible. Solo tendrias que denifir ambos objetos como encriptables y enviarla instancia del Encriptador. Mira el ejemplo actualizado. Fijate que `RecordMedico` tiene un objeto Paciente que tambien es encriptable y mira como en la clase `RecordMedico` encripta a `Paciente`. Y si `Paciente` tiene otro objeto encriptable, entonce se hace lo mismo que en `RecordMedico`.

Comment: Muy buena respuesta Einer.